# What does this JPA persist failure mean? "Error Code:0 Call: INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (?)"

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink

I'm using JPA to persist a POJO to an MSSQL table. I got an exception. It happens on `EntityManager.persist(pojo);`  in the following function:

```
private static void runTransaction(String name) {
    // Create the EntityManager
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("aeosclientPU");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Tst tst = new Tst();
    tst.setName(name);
    tst.setId(1);       //I commented out this line, but get the same exception with id=null
    em.persist(tst);    //here Exception
    em.flush();                     
    em.getTransaction().commit();   
    em.close();
    factory.close();
    System.out.println("FERTIG");
}

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception 
[EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO tst (name) VALUES (?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(aeospojo.Tst[ id=1 ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:868)
at Test.TestTst.runTransaction(TestTst.java:38)
at Test.TestTst.run(TestTst.java:26)
at aeosclient.Aeosmain.main(Aeosmain.java:10)
...
```

`Tst` is a POJO, an entity class from MSSQL table "tst" that I created before. The tst table looks like this:
[image]

What does the exception above mean and how can I fix it ?

Comment: "java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation" - you are inserting data larger then the column size of the database.  Name is too long a string.  What size of 'name' do you need to support?  You should increase the name column in the database from 10 to the max size you need to support, and add validation so you don't try to insert values larger then this in the future.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Your suggestion solves the problem.